# How to use a float in an "if x in range" statement

Tags: python, if-statement, range

I'm trying to write an `if` statement that takes a float as a range.

```
x = 8.2

if x in range(0, 4.4):
    print('one')
if x in range(4.5, 8):
    print('two')
if x in range(8.1, 9.9):
    print('three')
if x > 10:
    print('four')
```

I have also tried this to no avail:

```
if x > 0 <= 4.4
```

Comment: `if 0 <= x <= 4.4`

Comment: What output do you want if `x` is, say, 4.45? Your ranges do not cover all non-negative real numbers.

Comment: Also, `x > 0 <= 4.4` means `x > 0 and 0 <= 4.4`, and the latter is of course uninteresting. You need to use the chained comparison syntax suggested by @Barmar.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `range()`. Just use comparisons, and use `elif` so that the ranges are exclusive.

```
if x < 4.5:
    print('one')
elif x < 8:
    print('two')
elif x < 10:
    print('three')
else:
    print('four')
```

This also solves the problem that you had gaps between your ranges.

Comment: would there be issues with values such as x=4.56 or x=8.01?

Comment: No, that's the reason I didn't put boundaries at both ends of the ranges.

Comment: `4.56` will print `two`, `8.01` will print `three`.

Comment: What should be printed when `x == 10`? It's not in the range `8.1 to 9.9`, but it's not `> 10` either.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
if 0 < x <= 4.4:
```

where `x` is in the middle. It's equivalent to

```
if 0 < x and x <= 4.4:
```

`range` is not suitable for that task.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 8.3

if 0 <= x <= 4.4:
    print('one')
if 4.5 <= x <= 8:
    print('two')
if 8.1 <= x <= 9.9:
    print('three')
if x > 10:
    print('four')
```

Answer (score 0):

For floating points you don't need to use range instead you can use comparisons operators like:

```
num = 4
if (num > 3.3) print("less than four")
elif (num > 3.7) print("less than four")
elif (num > 3. 9) print("less than four")
else print("Equal to four")
```