# Using range with decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting an error code for this code and don't know how to get around it.

```
score = int(input("Enter an CVSS Score: "))
if score <= 0:
    print("Risk Score = None")
elif score in range(0.1, 3.9):
    print("Risk Score = Low")
```

I just need to able to only put in numbers 1-10 but also allow things like 1.2 or 3.4.

Comment: Is there any reason why you did not want to use `elif 0.1 <= score <= 3.9` to check the score?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - How to use a float in a "if x in range" statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761317/python-how-to-use-a-float-in-a-if-x-in-range-statement)

Comment: Since `score` is an int, you could just use `range(1, 4)` to capture the values from 1 to 3.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

> The arguments to the range constructor must be integers

You're attempting to use `range` with `float`s (`0.1` and `3.9`). You can fix your code by changing it to:

```py
score = float(input("Enter an CVSS Score: "))  # cast input to float
if score <= 0:
    print("Risk Score = None")
elif 0.1 <= score < 3.9:  # check input is within bounds
    print("Risk Score = Low")
```